# Install OK but how can I make Ubuntu start without pressing F9?

Tags: boot, grub2

No problems during clean installation of Ubuntu 23.10 on a HP elitebook folio 9470m. But then at restart, no operating system is found. After Pressing <kbd>ESC</kbd><kbd>F9</kbd> I can select 3 boot options:
[image: Boot options]

Selecting option "ubuntu" starts booting Ubuntu. How can I make Ubuntu start without pressing <kbd>F9</kbd>?

Comment: Try a different boot order by entering the UEFI/BIOS menus and put the drive with Ubuntu at the top. If only one drive, you should be able to modify the order in the EFI file, so that 'ubuntu' comes before 'Boot From EFI File' but I don't know the details, because it depends on the UEFI/BIOS system of your computer (and this is outside Ubuntu).